# WebAPI in asp.net individual authentication

Tags: c#-4.0

For getting individual authentication,which is provided by the VS 2013 while designing  webAPI what i supposed to do . the relevant methods and validations are automatically come up with corresponding controller and model class .whats the next step ..?

Comment: Are you asking how to enable authentication on your webservice?

Comment: yes ... I've seen from the Web API template in Visual Studio that it auto creates some authentication for us, so maybe it will dictate what the table names must be . can u please teel me reagrding this authentication from the basic ..am very new to this one

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial that gets individual authentication running:
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api

The first paragraph says that the data is stored in a [SQLServer LocalDB](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/) database.